# Executing a command in vim from a commandline

Tags: command-line, vim

I would like to run `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` in vim, but from command line.

The purpose is to run the command occasionally with other commands to keep
my tools up-to-date (probably in a cron job on my development machine.

I looked around `man vim`, but cannot figure out what option I need to pass.

I think this is a general question for vim, but I'm using Mac and Ubuntu for the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `vim(1)` man page:

```
   +{command}

   -c {command}
               {command}  will  be  executed after the first file has been
               read.  {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.   If  the
               {command}  contains  spaces  it  must be enclosed in double
               quotes (this depends on the shell that is used).   Example:
               Vim "+set si" main.c
               Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.

     ...

   --cmd {command}
               Like using "-c", but the command is  executed  just  before
               processing  any  vimrc file.  You can use up to 10 of these
               commands, independently from "-c" commands.
```

Just put `:q!` as the final command if you want to get back out.